# iOS timecode-synced downloadable animation system

Tags: ios, animation, video, sprite-kit, scenekit

As an introduction and context, I'm currently a novice iOS app developer and I want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel too much as I make this app (reinventing wheels can get very expensive.)

The app will allow the user to download our videos off the internet and will allow storage for offline usage. The problem with storing these videos on the device is that many of them will be too long and thus too big to be practical to store.

The videos are quite simple however, consisting of a couple short "real" video clips at the beginning and end, with the bulk of the video being still images animated around the screen. The animations would consist solely of opacity and simple transformation keyframes (translate, scale, rotate around static anchor point), and would require a variety of easing functions for each transition.

The hardest part likely would be that the "video" player will also have to be able to track with an audio player's timecode, and will have to support seeking to any arbitrary point like a normal video player.

So, now that I've described the problem, here's the solution I've come up with so far. Hopefully doing it this way will reduce the probability of XY problems. :)

The idea is to basically do a dumbed-down version of what Final Cut and other editing programs do with animations—have a bunch of clips, sometimes overlapping, and be able to animate the position, scale, rotation, and opacity of each using keyframes.

My first instinct as far as implementation goes is to use some of iOS's game engine stuff to do animations (maybe SceneKit because it seems to allow animations to use scene time as opposed to real time, despite the fact that it's primarily 3d and I am doing 2d animations) and manually handle syncing time with the audio player, as well as manually handling the adding and removing of nodes from the scene when seeking through the video and when clips begin/end.

What are some built-in systems, plugins, etc. that I can take advantage of to make this easier and faster to develop and maintain? Double points if I don't have to transcode the animations by hand to some custom format.

Comment: Your question is too broad as is clear from the title already, I suggest editing out everything but the timing question and cover the rest in other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment your question is rather broad and contains multiple questions in one, I will address what you mentioned to be likely the hardest part: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset

Instead of SceneKit, take a look at SpriteKit and its [SKVideoNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skvideonode).

Also, research Metal video processing. There are quit a few example projects available you could use as a starting point.

Comment: You can use SKVideoNode with SceneKit

Comment: Yes but that is still no good reason to use SceneKit considering he mentioned he’s only going to do 2D animations.

Comment: it might be 3D with billboarding

Comment: AVFoundation turns out to be perfect! Thank you!

I got done in 6 hours what I thought would have taken several days!